# Creating a Functional Parser in F# using Visual Studio 2013 with FsLex and FsYacc

Tags: visual-studio, f#, fsyacc, fslex

I have been struggling for a while simply getting a parser to compile and work in F# Visual Studio 2013. I've read a lot of other posts already that seemed helpful, both on stack overflow and this page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing but nothing is working. I know how to write a parser and everything I just cannot get anything to compile correctly, and creating .fsl and .fsp files in Visual Studio 2013 does not seem very intuitive. This link: https://github.com/fsprojects/FsLexYacc/tree/master/tests/LexAndYaccMiniProject was helpful but it is missing Lexer.fs, Parser.fs, and Parser.fsi. Any help towards this would be greatly appreciated. I have been using the FsLexYacc package that can be installed on the package manager. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Trying to improve the question by adding some more information.
1) In Visual Studio I created a new Console Project and imported the FsLexYacc package
2) I made a .fs file that contains type definitions and such just like in the examples in the links posted above
3) This is where I'm having trouble. I know what to put inside of a .fsp and a .fsl file, but I do not know how to create them in visual studio and get them to compile correctly using the FsLex and FsYacc tools. The github link above goes into a  little detail about editing the .fsproj file, but nothing that I've tried has worked. I'm assuming in order to get the tools to create the .fsp and .fsl files that the tools create them from a plain .fs file, but I'm not sure and I don't know exactly how to do that, so clarification would be great.

To reproduce my problem, either follow the steps on the wiki page or copy the files from the github link to a new project, I can't get either to compile regardless.

This question is similar to mine but I also could not get mine to work following these answers: [Using FsLex/Yacc in Vs2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781156/using-fslex-yacc-in-vs2013/19784859#19784859)

Comment: You may need to post some code, otherwise it is hard to reproduce your problem.